# Why Chrome cancel CORS OPTION request

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, cors

in my app I'm creating AJAX request from HTTP to HTTPS. This means I need CORS. So I add some headers and params to jQuery.ajax and test it. In Firefox everythings works OK, but in Chrome not. Chrome "kill" every preflighed request (OPTIONS).

jQuery script:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.ajax', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax(this.href, {
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        crossDomain: false,
        headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

HTTP dump:

```
> OPTIONS /foo HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: local.bar.cz
> Accept: */*
> Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, origin, x-requested-with
> Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
> Origin:http://local.bar.cz
> 
< HTTP/1.1 204
< Server: nginx/1.2.7
< Date: Wed, 27 Feb 2013 15:06:54 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Powered-By: Nette Framework
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://local.bar.cz
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept, origin, x-requested-with
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, GET, POST, HEAD
<
```

any one knows why chrome kill this request?

Comment: What do you mean by Chrome "kills" the request? If you view the request in Chrome's console and network tab, what errors do you see? Is the actual request being made, or is the preflight failing?

Comment: In Chrome's console at network tab I have preflight (OPTIONS) request with status `(canceled)`.

Comment: Try clearing your `X-Requested-With` Field, make it ""

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Maybe your https server has an untrusted certificate. If so, try accessing to the URL with your browser first, and accepting the untrusted connection.

Comment: This is exactly the case. I had identical situation - NodeJS server with dummy self-signed certificate. After I've opened the URL in my browser everything went fine and Chrome stopped cancelling my OPTIONS requests.

Comment: BTW, beware using CORS, self-signed certs, and Google Chrome/Chromium. I just lost an entire morning to this: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=141839

Answer (score 12):

Accepting the certificate does not always solve this problem. If you use a self-signed cert, EVEN IF YOU ACCEPT IT FIRST, Chrome will still in some cases cancel your preflight OPTIONS requests. It's been this way since 2011:

- https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=96007

The workaround as noted in that page is to add the self-signed cert to your system's list of trusted certificates.

Instructions to do this on a Mac (modified slightly from original so that it works with OS 10.8.5 http://www.robpeck.com/2010/10/google-chrome-mac-os-x-and-self-signed-ssl-certificates/):

1. In the address bar, click the little lock with the X. This will bring up a small information screen.
2. Click the button that says “Certificate Information.”
3. Click and drag the certificate image to <strike>your desktop</strike> an open finder window (it doesn't appear to like dragging to desktop.
4. Double-click the created file. This will bring up the Keychain Access utility. Enter your password to unlock it.
5. Be sure you add the certificate to the System keychain, not the login keychain. Click “Always Trust,” even though this doesn’t seem to do anything.
6. After it has been added, double-click it. You may have to authenticate again.
7. Expand the “Trust” section. “When using this certificate,” set to “Always Trust”

You may need to restart Chrome for the cert to be fully trusted (the icon to change to a happy green lock in the url bar).

Answer (score 9):

Worth mentioning that there's ANOTHER case that yields absolutely *identically looking* results :

If you relocate the browser to a different URL (window.location ..) while waiting for a request to return (i.e. via a promise) then the OPTIONS request will be submitted but the subsequent response (POST/GET/*) will be cancelled (naturally ..)

Yes .. of course .. it's a bug if you do that .. but it might look just the same and consume hours of looking in the wrong place.
consider such a code :

```
makeAjaxCallThatReturnsAPromise.then(
    function () { // doSomething },
    function () { // doSomethingElse }
);
location.replace('http://some.where/');
```

Comment: I gotta say, this CORS failure is a real sleeper. It really is never written about and I have spent an embarrassing amount of time on it, prior to reading this. Because of timing issues which of course we have no control over, this was the issue. I had the window.location page change just BEFORE my ajax POST and I kept failing. After reading this answer I moved the window.location statement into the success:  code of my $.post statement and it worked.  If all else has been verified, then this must be checked!  Very helpful!  +1