# Angularjs $http GET method change to OPTION, while adding custom headers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cross-domain

```
var users= $resource('http://myapp.herokuapp.com/users', {});
users.get();
```

After adding header method, http GET method change to OPTION

```
var users= $resource('http://myapp.herokuapp.com/users', {}, {
    get:{
        method:"GET",
        headers:{'x-access-token':'token'}
    }
});

users.get();
```

Please guide me why GET method change to OPTION Method.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20671619/angularjs-options-preflight-call-preceding-a-http-post-request. Angular sends a preflight OPTIONS request to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preflight that causes confusion --> Preflight is an additional request the XHR object makes to make sure it's allowed to actually make the request

Check out https://remysharp.com/2011/04/21/getting-cors-working

Answer (score 1):

Following REST conventions, an OPTION call is being made before the GET call.

To quote the spec:

> This method allows the client to determine the options and/or
>   requirements associated with a resource, or the capabilities of a
>   server, without implying a resource action or initiating a resource
>   retrieval.