# angularjs doesnt POST to my django based apis - giving CORS error

Tags: angularjs, django, cors, django-cors-headers

This has been plaguing me for quite a while now. I've set up a basic set of apis in Django and am building an angularJS based front end. However for some weird reason the following code results in a CORS error.

```
    var req = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: url,
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
  withCredentials: true,
  param: data,
  data: data
}

return $http(req).then(
        function(response){
          callbackSuccess(response);
        },
        function(response){
          callbackError(response);
        }
      );
```

I found out two things that when I do a post an OPTIONS request is made and secondly none of what I post is even posted. I try to out put the request.POST contents and its empty.

```
Internal Server Error: /api/users/auth/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ali/eb-virt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/ali/eb-virt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/ali/eb-virt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ali/eb-virt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 149, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ali/Projects/api.project.local/project/api/views.py", line 50, in loginUser
    emailAddress = request.POST["emailAddress"]
  File "/home/ali/eb-virt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 85, in __getitem__
    raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key))
MultiValueDictKeyError: "'emailAddress'"
[21/Nov/2016 07:56:59] "OPTIONS /api/users/auth/ HTTP/1.1" 500 81083
```

And this is my server code:

```
def loginUser(request):
  emailAddress = ''
  password = ''
  emailAddress = request.POST["emailAddress"]
  password = request.POST["password"]



  data = auth.login(emailAddress, password)

  return data
```

I've installed the [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/) and followed all the instructions to the core but its still not working...

Comment: post your server code. you are accepting `OPTION` method inside view.'

Comment: I added the server code - I'm checking for POST - how do I accept OPTION method? doing a   pp.pprint of the request.POST outputs an empty dict object

Comment: You need to tell your server what requests to accept (POST, GET ...) and also from whom it can accept. Those are 2 headers that you need to set. Did you set them ?

Comment: How do I do that - I've made the setting CORS_ALLOW_METHODS in settings to include POST and GET but it seems to be ignored here..

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in Line :

```
emailAddress = request.POST["emailAddress"]
```

In the place of this line,use this code:

```
def loginUser(request):

  if request.method == 'POST':
    emailAddress = request.POST.get('emailAddress')  
    password = request.POST.get('password') 

    data = auth.login(emailAddress, password)

    return data
```

**request.POST["emailAddress"]** will raise a KeyError exception if 'emailAddress' is not in request.POST.

While **request.POST.get('emailAddress')** will return None if 'emailAddress' is not in request.POST.

Comment: Thats the problem even if I do this nothing is POSTED even though I'm doing a post request with actual values. The above code sets emailAddress to None.

Comment: @Ali Updated my answer.Please check now.

Comment: Noted but heres where another problem occurs. from the front end I'm doing a POST request but on the back end its treated as an OPTIONS request so the above updated code is never executed as request.method is equaling OPTIONS for some weird reason.

Comment: @Ali You need to make sure that the emailAddress and password fields are getting passed with post request.

Comment: @Ali Did you use csrf token??

Comment: @Ali This is a new problem.I corrected your earlier code and this is not mentioned  anywhere in the original question.

Comment: @Ali try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20671619/angularjs-options-preflight-call-preceding-a-http-post-request

Comment: A csrftoken is passed - I can see it in my firebug console panel. However what beats me is that ist passed as POST but django registers an OPTIONs request and the values passed are all lost :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128611/discussion-between-prakhar-trivedi-and-ali).

Answer (score 1):

`OPTION` request is doing by your browser for a safety whether it can send POST request(in case of cross domain). It should return a 200 with some headers(will take care of `cors-headers` middleware if you added it).
So In server, accept `POST` request this way(assume function based views).

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    #access POST variables here.
```

Comment: @Ali , `OPTION` request is doing by your browser for a safety whether it can send `POST` request(in case of cross domain).

Comment: Yeh figured that out found the issue :) thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue - was a total noob mistake.

My version of Django in my virtual environment was 1.9 whereas I had generated the project from a version 1.10 so in the settings the `MIDDLEWARE` option had to be named as `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` - silly mistake had me stuck for two days - thanks everyone for all your answers :)