# Ionic 3/Angular 4/5 http post - not found

Tags: angular, post, ionic-framework, httpclient

In postman, I have:

```
POST:    https://myapp.herokuapp.com/login
BODY:     {"email": "myemail@gmail.com", "password": "123456"}
```

and it works.

In  provider, I have:

```js
public login(credentials): Observable<any> {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json'
      })};

    return this.http.post(API_URL + '/login', {params: {email: credentials.email, password: credentials.password}}, httpOptions);
  }
```

I get `Not Found` error. In console in Network tab, request method is OPTIONS. What is wrong?

EDIT: I get following error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try without `params`:

```
public login(credentials): Observable<any> {
    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type':  'application/json'
        })
    };

    return this.http.post(API_URL + '/login', {email: credentials.email, password: credentials.password}, httpOptions);
}
```

If this doesn't work then this may be occurring due to `CORS` requests, this is something called [**Preflighted request**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests). Browser always sends the `OPTIONS` request to server when you invoke `CORS` requests to know what methods are actually allowed.

See more:

- [Why am I getting an OPTIONS request instead of a GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256593/why-am-i-getting-an-options-request-instead-of-a-get-request)
- [Angular2 OPTIONS method sent when asking for http.GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36353532/angular2-options-method-sent-when-asking-for-http-get)
- [AngularJS: OPTIONS preflight call preceding a $http.post request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20671619/angularjs-options-preflight-call-preceding-a-http-post-request)